# Firebase remove test devices on console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Where on the firebase console can I remove `Test devices`? My app is not sending verification code for phoneAuth and I think this might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

On the console, got to `authentication`-> `add test numbers` The numbers you have will be shown and a delete icon on the right. Use that to delete the numbers you want to remove as test numbers.